# How to see if an attribute of a table appears in another table more than once on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables A and B.
Table A has 6 attributes (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) and table B has 4 (z,x,c,v). Attribute x is foreign key of attribute a. How to have all the lines in table a if a line in table B appears more 3 times or more?

Example
A

```
a b c d e f g      
1 w w w w w w    
2 w w w w w w
```

---

B - is a result from a select

```
z x v b
1 1 z z
2 1 z z
3 1 z z
```

---

return

```
1 w w w w w
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a subquery that returns all the `x`s for which there are 3 same rows in table B.

```
select * from A
where a in (
  select x from B
  group by x, v, b
  having count(*) >= 3
)
```

Comment: Replace B with the select statement that returns B, like: `...in ( select t.x from (select.....) t group by t.x, t.v, t.b)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and `join`:

```
select a.*
from (select x
      from b
      group by x
      having count(*) > 2
     ) b join
     a
     on b.x = a.a
```

Comment: what if B is a result of a select?

Comment: select a.*
from (select x
      from (select * from b where something)
      group by x
      having count(*) > 1
     ) b join
     a
     on b.x = a.a

Comment: @AdathSkyderson . . . (1) You would just use a subquery or CTE.  (2) Your question specifies a table.